# Is it necessary to know initial y velocity to solve this projectile motion problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, projectile

> A marble is launched horizontally off a 93.0-cm high table causing the marble to land on the floor 1.85 m from the base of the table.
>
> a.) How long was the ball in the air?
> b.) With what velocity must the marble have left the tabletop?

Wouldn't another piece of information be needed to solve this problem?

Is it implied the initial y velocity is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it it implied that the $y$-component of the initial velocity is zero because the problem states that "the marble is launched horizontally."